# is it possible to get current display measurement units in vb.net for Office?

Tags: vb.net

In my VSTO add-in for Office, it would be useful for me to know which unit of measurement the user has chosen for their interface (specifically, the add-in needs to know if the ruler in a Word document is shown in Inches or Centimeters or other units of measurement). Is it possible to retrieve this information using VB.NET? I can retrieve the current system language or interface language using things like:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
My.Application.Culture
My.Application.UICulture
```

And it seems I can get information about whether the current system culture is metric or not:

`System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric`

However this doesn't necessarily correspond with the chosen display units in a Word document, as can be set from the **Word Options** dialog box under the **Display** section ("Show measurements in units of:" dropdown). Is there any way of retrieving this using vb.net?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea where to look for this. However, I do have a process that has worked in the past for finding random settings in the Word/Office VBA APIs.

What I do is use the "**Record Macro**" feature to see what code is generated when I change the setting in question. Then I can use reference that code to know what to check.

Using that process on this question to change inches to centimeters generated this code:

```
Options.MeasurementUnit = wdCentimeters
```

I then modified the macro to alert on `Options.MeasurementUnit`:

```
MsgBox(Options.MeasurementUnit)
```

The result is `1`. I changed it back to "Inches" and ran it again, and I saw a `0`. You can continue to this to find the correct value for each of item in the dropdown for that setting.

Comment: Okay that gave me a head start, I believe I have the solution in vb.net. Inside of my class I am using:

`Private Application As Word.Application = Globals.MyAddIn.Application
Private unitPref As Word.WdMeasurementUnits = Application.Options.MeasurementUnit
`

Answer (score 0):

The [answer from Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563523/394921) got me on track. From within a VSTO add-in in vb.net, I was able to verify that the correct way to retrieve this information is like this (given that the add-in is for Microsoft Word):

```vb
Dim Application As Word.Application = Globals.{MyAddIn}.Application
Dim units As Word.WdMeasurementUnits = Application.Options.MeasurementUnit
```

(switch out {MyAddIn} with the actual add-in namespace)